# compare char* with each other

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I currently have a method called getResult which returns const char* now I am doing something like this

```
if(getResult=="Something")
{
  ...
}
```

However it seems this type of comparison doesn't work. Isn't "Something" also a const char pointer ?  or in this case are the addresses being compared?

Comment: `if(std::string(getResult) == "Something")`?

Comment: @Rapptz thanks that works. Could you post why my way was not working so that I could close this question.

Comment: Because you can't compare const char* strings with `operator==`. Other answers explain this too.

Comment: Maybe this will clear things up. const char* is not a class, it is just an array of char values. The only way to compare things beyond basic integers is by operator overloading. I suggest you read up on C++ operator overloading. The string class has the "==" operator overloaded so it can perform the comparison. Operator overloading is one of C++'s great language features that allows for super powerful programming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `getResult` is a method (member function) you need to *call* it to compare the result, so you probably want:

```
if (something.getResult() == std::string("Something"))
  // ...
```

If, on the other hand, `getResult` is really a pointer to char (or pointer to const char), you need to convert one of the things you're comparing to `string` before the comparison):

```
if (getResult == std::string("Something"))
```

or:

```
if (std::string(getResult) == "something))
```

IMO, this *should* almost never be necessary -- instead of starting with a pointer to [const] char, then converting, you should normally use `std::string` throughout.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, the addresses are being compared. To compare the *contents* of two strings, use the [`strcmp`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) function:

```
if (strcmp(getResult, "Something") == 0) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you compare 2 string constants in C/C++ you compare the actual address of each string, not the content. Using `strcmp` on 2 c-strings or using C++'s `std::string` class will compare the content.